# Life imitates chess: is a player' style of play determined by personality and can style of play be altered?

Tags: positional-play, training, attack

There's a popular saying along the lines of *"life imitates chess"*, my understanding is that *cool, calm and collected* players like Karpov will tend to opt for positional play while *unsettled skittish* players like Kasparov and Tal will drift towards aggressive play.

Does this mean that if you are *cool* by nature your style of play will lean more towards positional play than risky aggressive play and can style of play be acquire through training?

Comment: @Rewan Demontay Not everything that has to be discussed has to be based on scientific studies and scientific studies haven't been carried out on each and every subject, at times matters that interest us stem from personal experience. The great Garry Kasparov had made a similar assertion and wrote a book without the backing of scientific studies, therefore I would like to find out more about it from the chess community and expand my knowledge.

Comment: @RewanDemontay Yes, because scientific studies are eternal truth and never subject to the researcher's biases and need to publish some positive result. I have a very interesting publication for you: https://journals.plos.org/plosmedicine/article?id=10.1371/journal.pmed.0020124

Comment: Unfortunately that's just the nature of Stack Exchange - the questions are not meant to be opinion based. If you edit it to be more objective, such as asking about what else has been said about this by prominent members of the chess community, you could get it reopened.

Comment: On what basis would you evaluate Kasparov as "unsettled and skittish"?  He is nothing of the sort.